Why so many commas?

What was new, however, was that, for the first time in a long time, he was tired because of something as mundane as a long walk.

There are so many commas in this sentence that it seems very complex, and I'm not sure if the sentence is grammatically correct. Why are there so many commas?

Please give the source of the sentence you are asking about. There are no hard-and-fast rules about commas; it's a matter of stylistic choice. It looks fine to me.

I could find this structure only in writings not usually conversations. However, the sentence is grammatically correct to me.

I’m voting to close this question because ELL is not a grammar-checking service.

@hwkal, how does anyone find punctuation 'in conversations'?

@PaulTanenbaum I think there is a good question hiding beneath the request for it to be checked. The OP felt the sentence was very complex, but I've tried to make it less complex in my answer, which they have accepted. I've edited the question to try and bring it more on-topic

You say there are "so many commas", but there are just two sets of parenthetical commas in the sentence. Learn to spot them and it will help you comprehend the grammar.
Parentheses can be commas or brackets (like this). They offset nonessential information from the rest of the sentence. They are usually pairs because they 'open' and 'close' the parenthetical information, although an afterthought can follow a single comma at the end of a sentence.
You could write it without that parenthetical information and it would make sense without any commas:

What was new was that he was tired because of something as mundane as a long walk.

"However" in this kind of context is a nonessential adverb or a parenthetical adverb. It serves a purpose - to indicate a contrast. But you could probably spot the contrast anyway. This sentence is speaking about something "new", so presumably the previous sentences spoke about things that were not new.
"for the first time in a long time" is an adverbial phrase. It could be important information, but in your example, the writer has made it parenthetical, so, apparently, they do not consider it important to the point being made.
